# Duplicación visual de elementos al usar react-dnd en React Drag and Drop en

Tags: html, reactjs, drag-and-drop, next

Estoy enfrentando un problema en mi aplicación React al utilizar la biblioteca react-dnd para implementar la funcionalidad de arrastre y suelta de elementos. La aplicación tiene una lista de widgets que pueden ser arrastrados y reorganizados.

El problema ocurre cuando arrastro un widget. El widget se duplica visualmente en la interfaz de usuario, y ambos elementos duplicados comparten el mismo id y index. Esto ocurre incluso cuando el widget debería estar siendo arrastrado correctamente.

He revisado la lógica de mi componente WidgetDraggable y parece estar manejando correctamente el estado y la posición de los widgets al arrastrarlos. Sin embargo, la representación visual muestra la duplicación del mismo widget.

Adjunto el código relevante:

````
'use client';
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useDrag, useDrop, DndProvider } from 'react-dnd';
import { HTML5Backend } from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
import IconRoundedButton from "@/app/components/buttons/IconRoundedButton";
import { Icon } from "@iconify/react/dist/iconify.js";
import BigWidgetCard from '@/app/components/cards/BigWidgetCard';
import WidgetCard from '@/app/components/cards/WidgetCard';

interface Widget {
  id: number;
  content: React.ReactNode;
}
interface WidgetDraggableProps {
  id: number;/*  */
  index: number;
  moveWidget: (fromIndex: number, toIndex: number) => void;
  isEditing: boolean;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const WidgetDraggable: React.FC<WidgetDraggableProps> = ({ id, index, moveWidget, isEditing, children }) => {
  const [{ isDragging }, ref] = useDrag({
    type: 'WIDGET',
    item: { id, index } as { id: number; index: number },
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isDragging: !monitor.isDragging(),
    }),
  });
  console.log(isDragging);

  const [, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: 'WIDGET',
    hover: (item: { id: number; index: number }) => {
      if (item.index !== index) {
        moveWidget(item.index, index); // Actualizar el índice a través de la función moveWidget
        item.index = index; // No modificar directamente el índice en el objeto item
        console.log(item.index);
      }
    },
  });

  return (
    <div ref={(node) => ref(drop(node))} style={{ cursor: isEditing ? 'move' : 'auto' }}>
      {React.cloneElement(children as React.ReactElement, {
        isDraggingWidget: isEditing,
        style: {
          opacity: isDragging ? 0.5 : 1,
          display: isDragging ? 'none' : 'block',
        },
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const PlantMeasuresPage: React.FC = () => {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const initialWidgets: Widget[] = [
    {
      id: 1, content: <WidgetCard
        icon="la:sun"
        title="Corba de potència diària"
        description="kW generats, consumits, autoconsumits i bateria durant el dia"
        isDraggingWidget={isEditing} >
      </WidgetCard>
    },
    {
      id: 2, content:
        <WidgetCard
          icon="la:tree"
          title="Compromís mediambiental"
          description="Co2 estalviat fins avui"
          isDraggingWidget={isEditing} >
        </WidgetCard>
    },
    {
      id: 3, content:
        <WidgetCard
          icon="la:bolt"
          title="Balanç d'energies"
          description="Energia produïda, consumida i autoconsumida durant el dia"
          isDraggingWidget={isEditing} >
        </WidgetCard>
    },
    {
      id: 4, content:

        <WidgetCard
           icon="la:piggy-bank"
           title="Estalvis de planta"
           description="€ estalviat fins avui"
           isDraggingWidget={isEditing} >
         </WidgetCard>
     },
    // {
    //   id: 5, content:
    //     <WidgetCard
    //       icon="la:sun"
    //       title="Pronòstic de la irradiancia solar"
    //       description="Predicció de la irradiancia solar segons la localització de la planta"
    //       isDraggingWidget={isEditing} >
    //     </WidgetCard>
    // },
    // {
    //   id: 6, content:

    //     <WidgetCard
    //       icon="la:cloud-sun"
    //       title="Predicció meteorològica"
    //       description="Predicció meteorològica dels propers dies"
    //       isDraggingWidget={isEditing} >
    //     </WidgetCard>
    // },
    // {
    //   id: 7, content:
    //     <WidgetCard
    //       icon="la:chart-bar-solid"
    //       title="Rendiment de la planta"
    //       description="Rendiment de la planta segons irradiància solar i potència instal·lada"
    //       isDraggingWidget={isEditing} >
    //     </WidgetCard>
    // },

  ];
  const [widgets, setWidgets] = useState<Widget[]>(initialWidgets);

  const moveWidget = (fromIndex: number, toIndex: number) => {
    setWidgets((prevWidgets) => {
      const updatedWidgets = [...prevWidgets];
      const [movedWidget] = updatedWidgets.splice(fromIndex, 1);
      updatedWidgets.splice(toIndex, 0, movedWidget);
      return updatedWidgets;
    });
  };

  const resetPosition = () => {
    setWidgets(initialWidgets);
  };

  return (
    <div className="px-14 pt-12 pb-32">
      <div className="flex mb-6">
        <div className="w-10/12">
          <h1 className="font-manropeExtraBold text-3xl">ManVilazano</h1>
        </div>

        <div className="w-2/12  flex relative pt-2 md:block">
          <span className="float-right mr-1">
            <IconRoundedButton iconName="la:file-download"></IconRoundedButton>
          </span>

          <span className="float-right mr-14">
            <IconRoundedButton iconName={isEditing ? "la:save" : "la:edit"}
              onClick={() => {
                setIsEditing(!isEditing)
                console.log("CHANGE EDIT STATE")
              }}
            />
          </span>

          <span className="float-right mr-14">
            <IconRoundedButton iconName="la:power-off" onClick={resetPosition} />
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>


      {/* <BigWidgetCard
        icon="la:network-wired"
        title="Sinòptic en temps real"
        description="Última actualització: 7/11/2023 8:31:06 GMT +02:00"
      >
      </BigWidgetCard> */}

      <div className="border-solid border-4 border-gray-600 grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-6 mt-6">
        {isEditing ? (
          <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
            {widgets.map((widget, index) => (
              <WidgetDraggable
                key={widget.id}
                id={widget.id}
                index={index}
                moveWidget={moveWidget}
                isEditing={isEditing}
              >
                {widget.content}
              </WidgetDraggable>
            ))}
          </DndProvider>
        ) : (
          widgets.map((widget, index) => (
            <div key={widget.id}>
              {widget.content}
            </div>
          ))
        )}
      </div>
    </div>


  );
};






export default PlantMeasuresPage;



``` codigo componente widget
````

"use client"
import { Icon } from "@iconify/react/dist/iconify.js";
import { useState } from "react";
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import clsx from "clsx";
import IconRoundedButton from "../buttons/IconRoundedButton";

export default function WidgetCard({
children, title, description, icon, isDraggingWidget
}: {
children?: React.ReactNode
title?: string,
description?: string,
icon?: string,
isDraggingWidget?: boolean
}) {

const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

return (
<motion.div layout className={clsx('w-full', { 'fixed top-0 left-0 h-full p-7 z-10': open })}>
<div className={clsx(
'bg-white rounded-2xl',
{
'h-full border border-neutralGrey200': open,
'h-fit': !open
}
)}>

```
      <div className="h-20 border-b border-neutralGrey200 pt-3.5 pl-12 relative">

        <div className="flex items-center">
          {icon ? <Icon icon={icon} className="text-2xl mr-4"></Icon> : <span></span>}
          <h2 className="font-manropeBold text-lg">{title}</h2>
        </div>

        <div className="mt-1">
          <p className="font-manropeRegular text-sm text-blueGrey200">{description}</p>
        </div>

        <div className="absolute top-5 right-6">
          {
            isDraggingWidget ? 
              <IconRoundedButton iconName="la:bars"></IconRoundedButton>
            :
              !open ?
                <IconRoundedButton iconName="eva:expand-fill" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}></IconRoundedButton>
              :
                <IconRoundedButton iconName="eva:collapse-fill" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}></IconRoundedButton>
          }

        </div>

      </div>

      <div className="border-t border-neutralGrey200">
        <div className="h-56">{children}</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</motion.div>
```

)
}